# Sum of factors of a huge number.

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, factoring

I recently appeared in a math olympiad and it had this one question which had me stumped. This was a few weeks back and I have been looking for a way to find its answer ever since, but with no success. Searched the internet for the solution, but couldn't find any on it too! Anyway, here's how the question goes:

The value of $2^{96} - 3^{16}$ has two factors between 60 and 70. What is the sum of these two factors?

BTW, I should add that I did use wolframalpha to actually find the answer so I am more interested in knowing how to work it out manually than just knowing the answer. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: the only primes between 60 and 70 are 61 and 67. You can compute the modular powers rather quickly.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Post as an answer, I would like to see

Comment: @YvesDaoust As the question is stated it doesn't specifically ask for PRIME factors.

Comment: @Honza Brabac Although it's not that hard to see that the only other number you would need to check is $65$ since the other are divisible by $2$ or $3$.

Comment: @HonzaBrabec: I knew someone would raise that. This is just a good heuristic guess. It works here and this is not pure coincidence. [If not, no harm, the other factors can be tried similarly.]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Using $a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$
\begin{align*}
2^{96}-3^{16}
={} &
(2^{48}+3^8)(2^{48}-3^8)
\\
={} &
(2^{48}+3^8)(2^{24}+3^4)(2^{24}-3^4)
\\
={} &
(2^{48}+3^8)(2^{24}+3^4)(2^{12}+3^2)(2^{12}-3^2)
\\
={} &
(2^{48}+3^8)(2^{24}+3^4)(2^{12}+3^2)(2^6+3)(2^6-3)
\end{align*}
and $2^6+3=67$, $2^6-3=61$, ...

Comment: That's ingenious! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome :)! Anyway, I just found two factors between 60 and 70, but I didn't prove they are unique.. A strict proof would require a bit more effort I guess, but you can come to a complete answer using some of the posted comments and the intuition by @YvesDaoust

Answer (score 3):

Modulo $61$:
$$2^6=64=3,2^{12}=9,2^{24}=81=20,2^{48}=400=34,\color{green}{2^{96}}=1156=\color{green}{58},$$
$$3^2=9=2^{12},\color{green}{3^{16}}=2^{96}=\color{green}{58}.$$

Similarly, modulo $67$ yields twice $25$.

---

Actually there is no need to perform the whole computation. Just observe

$$2^{12}\equiv3^2\mod61,\\2^{12}\equiv3^2\mod67.$$